# Xpath - get text separated by <p> tags

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I can't figure out how to get formatted text using xpath from tag which contain's many `<span>` tag's and `<p>` tag's.

It's in this form:

```
<span>This</span>
<span> is</span>
<span> main</span>
<span> text</span>
<p><span>First</span>
   <span>p-tag</span<
</p>
<p> second p tag ....
```

So there are two types of tag. `<p>` mean's that the text inside this tag is on new line. And text itself is divided into many substring's in `<span>` tag's.

The problem is that there are text's which are not inside `<p>`.

From the snippet above, I would like to get (for example in list):

```
['This is main text','First p-tag','seco....]
```

This work's but it get's only texts inside `<p>` tags:

```
def get_popis_url(url):
    root = get_root(url)
    ps = root.xpath('//div[@class="description"]/p')
    for p in ps:
        text = p.xpath('string()').replace('&nbsp',' ').strip()
        print text
```

So the result for the html snippet above is:

```
First p-tag
second p tag
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why are you not trying this :- `//div[@class="description"]/*`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure which Python library you are using (xml.etree?). But concering the XPath try `'.//div[@class="description"]//*'`. That will select all subelements beginnen at the `div`.

Using xml.etree it would look like this (assuming the HTML source code is given as a string):

```
def get_popis_url(html_source):
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    root = ET.fromstring(html_source)
    ps = root.findall('.//div[@class="description"]//*')
    for p in ps:
        text = p.text
        if text:
            print text.replace('&nbsp;',' ').strip()
```